# Record hyperlink inside trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I created a record hyperlink and sending it over an email but when I click the link the record id in the URL is changing like this '%7Ba006F00003dLUwDQAW%7D'

[image]

```
trigger UserReqNotification on Sfdc_user_request__c (after insert) {

    Set<Id> allInsertedIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
    System.debug(allInsertedIds);

    Sfdc_user_request__c userRes = [SELECT Id, Salesforce__C, Notified_System_Owner__c, Servicemax__C, Role__c, Profile__c, Department__c,Division__c, Title__c, Position__c,QA_Sandbox__c FROM Sfdc_User_Request__c where id = :allInsertedIds];

    String link = '<a href="https://ap1.salesforce.com/' + allInsertedIds + '">User request : ' + allInsertedIds + '</a>';
    //String link = '<a href="https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+ String.valueOf(allInsertedIds) +'">User request : '+ allInsertedIds + '</a>';

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
    sendTo.add('ranjankumar@gmail.com');
    for (Sfdc_user_request__c ur : trigger.new) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setSubject('SFDC User request');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('New SFDC User Request');
        //String body =  '<a href='+ ur.Id +'></a>';
        //mail.setPlainTextBody('https://tapp0.salesforce.com/'+allInsertedIds);
        mail.setHtmlBody(link);
        mails.add(mail);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are trying to insert `Set` of Ids inside `allInsertedIds`.

Set inserts a `{` and `}` which when in `UTF-8` converts to `%7B` and `%7D` respectively.

Thus it would be better if you are looping on the `Map` returned from `Trigger.newMap` then add a `a` and `<br>` tag separately for each ids.

First use only Map as your context is `after insert`

`Map<Id, Sfdc_user_request__c> sObjectsByIds = Trigger.newMap;`

```
String link = '';
for(Id sfdcUserRequestId  : sObjectsByIds.keySet()){
    sObjectsByIds.get(sfdcUserRequestId);
    link = link + '<a href="https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+ sfdcUserRequestId +'">User request : '+ sfdcUserRequestId + '</a> <br>';
    mail.setHtmlBody(link);
}
mails.add(mail);
```

Also I see you are sending it to only one address, so no need to creating those many emails. Just one instance with separate links for each user.

Or even this would work:

```
String link = 'User request : <br>';
for(Id sfdcUserRequestId  : sObjectsByIds.keySet()){
    sObjectsByIds.get(sfdcUserRequestId);
    link = link + '<a href="https://ap1.salesforce.com/'+ sfdcUserRequestId +'"> '+ sfdcUserRequestId + '</a> <br>';
    mail.setHtmlBody(link);
}
mails.add(mail);
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```